# Enabling CORS in Google App Engine Flexible Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, cors, axios

I am facing issues enabling CORS support for a ASP.NET CORE application that is hosted using Google App Engine and the flexible environment.

Every AJAX request using the axios library results in the following error...

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.[something].services/request'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Here the configuration of CORS on the web api:

```c#
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options => 
    options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", 
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials();
        }));

   // ...

   services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        System.Environment
              .SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS",
                          Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                          Configuration["GAE:Credentials"]));
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    // ...

    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response?

Comment: Make sure the `app.UseCors("MyPolicy")` is before any API endpoints you have defined (i.e., if the `// ...` part has any endpoints defined, move the `UseCors` above it). Also see if the results change if you add the [EnableCors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1#per-action) attribute to a specific controller or action.

Answer (score 0):

This type of CORS errors are usually obtained when a resource1 does cross-origin HTTP requests to another resource2 without the handler for resource2 returning an Access-Control-Allow-Origin: response header containing the value http://resource1.

With this in mind, the [http header handler](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_http_headers) configuration needs to be appropriately set in the application App.yaml file which is deployed in App Engine. Most browsers use the XMLHttpRequest object to make a cross-domain request,taking care of inserting the right headers and handling the CORS interaction with the server.

All these information above apply to App Engine Standard and not the App Engine Flex environment. That is because [CORS requests are disallowed by default on App Engine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/release-notes#january_2017). However [you can allow CORS request by adding this "x-google-endpoints"  to your API configuration documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/release-notes#what_you_need_to_do)

Comment: The links you provide regarding App Engine Flex are specific to Extensible Service Proxy (ESP), and would only be relevant if the question is/was specific to ESP. GAE flex itself does not block CORS by default, and no changes to app.yaml are required for cross-domain requests.